# Updating issues

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I am trying to update some data on one APPlication  and sending the JMS Event to the different JBOSS server.
The listener will get the event and try to read the data using a  database view with dblink.

Initially this view has no data for that ID .I update the data using other Application and after comitting the JMS Event is sent  with that id. Once the listener received this id it will fetch the data using the database view.

My issue is that while reading with JPA/HIBERNATE it is still reading the old data which is comming as blank.

The service layer to call the dao layer is using the following transcation

```
    @Transactional(readOnly = true, propagation = Propagation.NOT_SUPPORTED)

    The DAO Layer is using 
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    Query query = em.createNativeQuery(sbQuery.toString());
```

I tried with all the following option and it doesnt seems to be work.

```
    em.clear();
    em.getEntityManagerFactory().getCache().evictAll();
    em.flush();
    query.setHint("javax.persistence.cache.storeMode", CacheStoreMode.BYPASS);
```

Note: The only way it works is  that  after i received the event if I do a staright jdbc i can fetch the data from that view but with spring/hibernate configuration its comming as blank.

Any thought why it's not working on the normal behaviour and why do I need to do a staright jdbc to the call?

Comment: do you have 2nd level cache configured? (and get rid of the not-supported propagation)

Comment: nope i dont have any 2 nd level Will try with to get rid of the not-supported configuration

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a standard scenario where the message is received before the transaction of the sender is committed. For it to work, you need to send the message after the transaction is committed. With spring you can do that via a `TransactionSynchornization`:

```
TransactionSynchronizationManager.registerSynchronization(new  
         MessageQueueTransactionSynchronization(jmsSender, message));
```

where `MessageQueueTransactionSynchronization` implements `TransactionSynchronization` and sends the message when `afterCompletion(..)` is triggered with `status = TransactionSynchronization.STATUS_COMMITTED`

Comment: thanks for the reply. I did couple of testing to make sure that I received the event only after the data is committed. The way I tested is once  I received the event from the onMessage method of the listener, I queried with Straight JDBC to the retrieve the data from the view, without the Spring Tranascation route to the Service Layer and it seems to be working. The only way I make a workaround is just invoke the view with Staright jdbc , and leave it and then call the Service layer to get the actual data with the view.

Comment: I am still confused why i need to do a call with straight jdbc to invoke the View Before I call the service layers to get the data from the view. If i don't invoke the view with straight jdbc and if I go directly with Spring Transaction Service layers i can see that the data is comming as nul

Comment: it's odd indeed. Is this happening on the same machine (both sender and recipient)? And check if you are for some reason reusing the same hibernate session/entity manager

Comment: thanks Bozho But no luck But i think i am not using the same session, really doubt about the Hibernate JPA Configuration

Comment: `MessageQueueTransactionSynchronization` is a class of yours that implements spring's `TransactionSynchronization`